# Wix XUtil xpath take second element not working

Tags: xml, xpath, wix

I want to select 2nd MyElement, if it already does not exits:

```
 <util:XmlConfig Id="CreateMyElement"
               File="[#MyXml.xml]"
               Action="create"
               ElementPath="/path/to/the/MyElement[2]/next/items"
               VerifyPath="/path/to/the/MyElement[2]/next/items/itemToAdd[\[]@MyAttribute='MyValue'[\]]"
               Name="itemToAdd"
               Node="element"/>
```

Unfortunately, the MyElement[2] does not work. Why ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the value of your VerifyPath should be in ElementPath , Also i dont think `Element[2]` Will work , use something like this instead :

```
/configuration/system.diagnostics/sources/source[\[]@name='Bla.Bla.Services.Mobile.UpdateService'[\]]/listeners/add
```

Comment: Yes, the [2] must look like: [\[]2[\]] , but unfortunately it does not work

Answer (score 0):

XPath expression in the form of, for example, `parent/MyElement[2]`, will pull out every second `<MyElement>` in each `<parent>` :

```
<parent>
    <MyElement>foo</MyElement>
    <MyElement>bar</MyElement><!-- This one will be returned by XPath -->
</parent>
```

If all `<parent>` elements in the XML document only have one or less `<MyElement>` child, then your XPath would return nothing. If you meant to return only the second `<MyElement>` element among all `<MyElement>` that matched by the beginning part of your XPath, you need to use parentheses, for example :

```
(/path/to/the/MyElement)[2]/next/items
```

Comment: Thank you, Is there a possiblility to select the last element in wix ?

Comment: @edekk XPath has [`last()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256083%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function which you can possibly use : `(/path/to/the/MyElement)[last()]`

Comment: Thank you but does Wix support it, I get en error when I try.

Comment: I believe WiX is using .NET implementation of XPath, and `last()` is indeed supported by .NET XPath. I'm not experienced with WiX tho so just a sanity check, have you properly escaped the square brackets as suggested in the other answer?

Answer (score 0):

The xpath in WiX appears to be 0 based

using the following in the wix .wxs file

```
    <util:XmlFile
      Id="SetLogPath"
      Action="setValue"
      File="[INSTALLFOLDER]Web.config"
      ElementPath="/configuration/log4net/appender[\[]0[\]]/file"
      Name="value"
      Value="[CONFIGDIR]\logs\log.log"/>
    <util:XmlFile
      Id="SetWarningLogPath"
      Action="setValue"
      File="[INSTALLFOLDER]Web.config"
      ElementPath="/configuration/log4net/appender[\[]1[\]]/file"
      Name="value"
      Value="[CONFIGDIR]\logs\warnings.log"/>
```

Updated the following 2 nodes.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="NormalLog" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender "/>
      <file value="D:\Config\logs\log.log"/>
      <threshold value="DEBUG"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
      <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%2thread] %-5level %-35.50logger{2} %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="WarningsLog" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender "/>
      <file value="D:\Config\logs\warnings.log"/>
      <threshold value="WARN"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
      <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%2thread] %-5level %-35.50logger{2} %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
```

I tried using 1 based indexing first but the second node was updated with log.log and then the installer failed trying to update a node it couldn't find.